# LaTeX editing discussions that are editor specific

Tags: discussion, community

Will it be appropriate on this forum to discuss LaTeX editing issues that are editor specific? For example, the two responses to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100/tool-for-cleaning-latex-code) are Emacs specific. While AUCTeX and RefTeX make Emacs-based LaTeX editing a dream, I imagine that the majority of the community might not be interested in arcane discussions of font customization in AUCTeX to make things like nice, etc., etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For any given question, the majority of the community will not be interested in it. Everybody has their own particular interests that generally span only a small part of the topic area of the site. So I'm inclined to say that editor-specific questions are okay, as long as the question relates primarily to *TeX and is not just a general question about an editor that someone happens to be using for *TeX editing.

Editor-specific answers to an editor-independent question (as in the example you linked to) are kind of a separate issue, but I'd say they're also okay. Some people will be amenable to using any editor that gives them access to a particular feature.

Comment: Yes, as long as it's useful to someone, answers are ok. An answer about an obscure editor that is useful to fewer people will probably get fewer upvotes, but that's the way the system is intended to work.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Of course, that would assume that the question was not about the same editor. In any case, I'll keep this in mind before I post any answers involving acme(1) or sam(1). (Of course, I'd also have to learn Plan9...)